# Navigate from a SKScene to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I want to navigate from a `SKScene` to a `UIViewController`. My code is as follows. However, when the method `showViewController()` is clicked the view doesn't get navigated. How can I solve this ?

I am using `SWIFT3` and `XCODE 8.1`

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    func showViewController() {
        print("button clicked")

        self.view!.window!.rootViewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "DashboardVIewControllerSegue", sender: self)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i have done to acheive this without having memory issue is.

first create some protocol(delegate) in the root viewController. This viewcontroller Contains the view as SKView where we load skscene.

so whenever you want to open a new viewcontroller from the skscene just call the protocol.

here is some code
In mainViewcontroller:

```
protocol GameProtocol {
    func displayViewController()
}
```

.

```
extension MainViewController: GameProtocol {

    internal func displayViewController() {


        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let popoverVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingViewController") as! SettingViewController
//        popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
//        popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popoverVC.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)

        popoverVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.popBackgroundColor
        popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popoverVC.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        popoverVC.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = self.view
        popoverVC.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, width: 0, height: 0)

        popoverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

        self.present(popoverVC,animated: false,completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have this code in maincontroller for popup alert when needed. within in gamescene.

and in game scene

```
  func showViewController() {
        let viewe = self.view as! GameSceneView
        viewe.myDelegate?. displayViewController()
    }
```

Hope you get this.